# Is it OK to edit a question you submitted an answer to?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, suggested-edits

In some cases, I have edited the title and tags of some questions and then answered.

A while ago, I revisited some of those questions and it felt awkward to see that I posted an answer and also edited the question (because a user can theoretically re-write a question completely), so I stopped editing questions that I'd answer.

Recently, I have found unanswered questions that I can answer, and sometimes those questions have incorrect tags, tags in titles and other details that I could fix as well.

Instead of struggling with myself to choose if I should or shouldn't do this I ask here.

Is it OK to edit a question you're posting an answer to? If it is, is there anything I should bear in mind to prevent any possible misunderstanding?

Comment: @Undo Thanks! Didn't find it using the search, though.

Comment: Search is fairly iffy for finding dupes. I just happened to see this and think, *Hey! I asked that!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely!

From time to time I answer a question and afterwards edit it to correct grammar, tags and so on. IMO it is good practice to improve a question you answered. It shows that you not only care about the rep but also that the question is in good shape for future visitors.